# Sum the fetched data

Tags: php, html, sql

Goodmorning guys! Here i want to do, I want to sum the two columns, `units_lab` and `units_lec` but when i run my code below the table became messy. What's the cause of this problem? Is my approach to sum the column is wrong? What is the correct approach for this?

[image]

```
if(isset($_POST['loadsgrade'])){
    $stud = $_POST['stud'];
        $output = '';  
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM grades WHERE stud_no ='$stud'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $output .= '
                  <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                      <tr>
                    <th>Subject Code</th>
                    <th>Section</th>
                    <th>Subject Decription</th>
                    <th>Units</th>
                    <th width="50">Prelim</th>
                    <th width="50">Midterm</th>
                    <th width="50">Finals</th>
                    <th width="100">Final Grade</th>
                      </tr>';

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
        $output .= '<tr>
                    <td>'.$row['subj_cd'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['section'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['subj_descr'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['units_lec'] + $row['units_lab'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['prelim_grade'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['midterm_grade'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['finals_grade'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['final_grade'].'</td>
                    </tr>
          ';
      }
          $output .= '</table>
            </div>';
   echo $output;


}
```

Comment: `table became messy.` what you mean by that? can you include SS

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. Use parameterized queries. You could also just add the 2 values in mysql. Awaiting "messy" definition.

Comment: @Nishanth Matha AND chriss85, I edit my question and added the SS. Take a look. But the answer below already fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the sum in `()` because otherwise PHP is confused about the `+` for numbers and the `.` for string concatenation.

```
<td>'. ($row['units_lec'] + $row['units_lab']) .'</td>
```